# Put number in list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, list-comprehension

**I have data in text box like this?**

```
12 14
13 15
16 17
```

i want to get them in list_comprehension  like this

```
['12','14']
['13','15']
['16','17']
```

How can i iterate over the text box data and put them in list like this?
Here is my code

```
    for w in form.vars.location_whitelist.split('\n'):
         line_loc = [x.split('\n')[0] for x in w]                                                                                  

         lac, cellid =line_loc[0] , line_loc[1]

         location_whitelist.append([lac , cellid])
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste your existing code? We don't know how these values are stored or anything else

Comment: Please Check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be over-complicating the lists. When iterating through the lines, `w` already represents each line. As a result, you only need to split `w` to get a list from each line.

*Note that I will be using `.splitlines()` instead of `.split('\n')`.*

```
original_text = \
"""12 14
13 15
16 17"""

list_comp = []
for w in original_text.splitlines():
     list_comp.append(w.split())

print(list_comp)

### Output:
### [['12', '14'], ['13', '15'], ['16', '17']]
```